# Cherry tree leave droopy and dried up

Tags: leaves, cherries, wind-damage

I recently bought a cherry tree in a wine barrel and now noticed its leaves are more droopy than usual and and are drying up. we water it everyday till water runs out the bottom of the barrel and the soil is moist.
We live in Cape Town and have a lot of wind not sure if that could be the issue.
[image: Potted cherry tree]

Comment: What type of cherry is it, a fruiting or ornamental one? Do you have the botanical name for it? Is it a dwarf or patio cherry tree? and lastly, what part of the world are you in?